# NSPredicate is not working for Filtering in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, filter, nspredicate

I have tried filtering by the NSPredicate. It's not working in the NSMutableArray, but I tried in the Array and it's working fine.

Working code using Array:

```
filterArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Yvan",@"Balu",@"Srinath",@"Aswin",@"Ram", nil];
NSPredicate *bPredicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] 'r'"];
NSArray *resultAr = [resultArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:bPredicate];
NSLog(@"Output %@",resultAr);
```

correctly produces:

```
Output (
Srinath,
Ram
)
```

I tried using NSMutableArray with containing Dictionary Data, but it's not working.

Framing the Result Array is:

```
for(int i=0;i<[priceArray count];i++)
    {
        cellDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        NSString *nameStr=nameArray[i];
        [cellDict setObject:nameStr forKey:@"Name"];
        [cellDict setObject:@([splPriceArray[i] intValue]) forKey:@"Percentage"];
        [cellDict setObject:@([priceArray[i] intValue]) forKey:@"Price"];
        [resultArray addObject:cellDict];
    }
```

Result Array:

```
(
        {
        Name = "Black Eyed Peas";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 80;
    },
        {
        Name = "Black Gram";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 56;
    },
        {
        Name = "Channa White";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 100;
    },
        {
        Name = "Double Beans";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 95;
    },
        {
        Name = "Gram Dall";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 100;
    },
        {
        Name = "Green Moong Dal";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 150;
    },
        {
        Name = "Ground Nut";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 140;
    },
        {
        Name = "Moong Dal";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 75;
    },
        {
        Name = "Orid Dal";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 100;
    },
        {
        Name = "Toor Dal";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 150;
    }
)
```

Tried Predicates Are:

```
//  NSPredicate *predit=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Price contains[c] '100'"];

NSPredicate *pred=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(Price == %@) AND (Percentage == %@)", @"100",@"0"];

NSArray *resultAr = [resultArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predit];
```

Is the above the correct way or is there a better way to implement it in order to get:

```
expected output:
(
            {
            Name = "Channa White";
            Percentage = 0;
            Price = 100;
        },
            {
            Name = "Gram Dall";
            Percentage = 0;
            Price = 100;
        },          
            {
            Name = "Orid Dal";
            Percentage = 0;
            Price = 100;
        }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Should be `Price` not `price`,should be `Percentage` not `percentage`
2. I guess `Percentage` is type of `NSNumber`

I test

```
    NSDictionary * dic1 = @{
                        @"Name" : @"Black Eyed Peas",
                        @"Percentage":@(0),
                        @"Price" : @(80),
                        };
    NSDictionary * dic2 = @{
                        @"Name" : @"Black Eyed Peas",
                        @"Percentage":@(0),
                        @"Price" : @(100),
                        };
    NSMutableArray * mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[dic1,dic2]];
    NSPredicate *pred= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(Price == %@) AND (Percentage == %@)", @(100),@(0)];

    NSArray *resultAr = [mutableArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
    NSLog(@"%@",resultAr);
```

Log

```
2015-07-20 22:11:44.535 OCTest[2192:79846] (
    {
    Name = "Black Eyed Peas";
    Percentage = 0;
    Price = 100;
}
)
```

Comment: sorry i tried that in different but 'p' is 'P' only,And i Update my question the Framing the Result Array but how can i implement your answer

Comment: Note,In my code,is @(100),that is NSNumber,not @"100"

Comment: Thanks it working now, i changed the @"100" & @"0" to @(100) & @(0)